# How to open a menu with Long hold or Right click in Angular2

Tags: angular, typescript

I am playing around with angular 2. I want to open a menu with 2,3 options on a mobile as well as on a pc.

What i need is, when i long hold or right click above the `div` with `class container` , i want a menu to be opened like this -

[image]

HTML code as follows:

```
<div class="container"   id="main-wrapper" >   
  <section class="intro">  
  <div class="content" >
    <h1 [contentEditable]="contentEditable" >You can create full screen sections without javascript.</h1>
    <p [contentEditable]="contentEditable">The height is set to 90vh, that means 90% height.</p>
 </div>
</section>
</div>
```

**explore.ts**

```
rightClickMenu(){
// What should i write in this function to get a menu as explained.
}
```

and where should I call this menu, please guide.

Comment: Check this [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/3klGukkbDBCOaBYqcGmr?p=preview).

Answer (score 1):

calculate the time between mouse up event and mouse down event if the time is > `time-specified then show the menu.

**in the component**

```
timeInterval:int =0
var k;
doMouseDown()
{
   timeInterval=0;
   k=setInterval(function(){
   timeInterval++;
},1000);
}

doMouseUp()
{
  clearInterval(k);
  if(timeInterval >15) // replace 15 with your time for long hold)
  {
   //open menu
  }
  else
  {
   //show for short hold 
  }
}
```

Comment: can you complete it by showing how to implement on my html and what exactly show i write in my ts file, will be helpful. I am getting advanced examples and i am unable to implement those

Comment: I am able to generate menu by right clicking on it using this tutorial -blog.sodhanalibrary.com/2016/10/display-customized-context-menu-on.html , but on right clicking the default browser window also opens, how can we switch this off and only our window opens, currently this is happening - https://www.dropbox.com/s/wqxkgfpozftsthe/Screenshot%202017-06-06%2000.48.23.png?dl=0 , please guide